# Loop through each customer records to get the first/last channel they came from

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have customer visit records with the channel they came from. I want to have one record per customer where I have the first channel they came from and the last channel they came from.

Another logic I need to add is that if the first channel is "Direct", then do not take it and look at the next record. If that next record is also "Direct", then do not take it either and look at the next record. If you finished all records for the customer and they were all "Direct", then you can make first channel "Direct".
I need the same logic for the last channel. Get the channel, if it is "Direct", then go to the previous one. If it is "Direct", then go through the previous record, until you finish all records.

The input data looks like this:

| Customer ID | Date | Channel |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1/1/24 | Email |
| 1 | 1/2/24 | Search |
| 1 | 1/3/24 | Direct |
| 2 | 1/5/24 | Direct |
| 2 | 1/6/24 | Paid |
| 2 | 1/7/24 | Email |
| 3 | 1/8/24 | Direct |
| 3 | 1/9/24 | Direct |
| 3 | 1/10/24 | Direct |
| 3 | 1/11/24 | Direct |

And the output I need is this:

| Customer ID | First Channel | Last Channel |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Email | Search |
| 2 | Paid | Email |
| 3 | Direct | Direct |

How can I do that in my DataFrame?

Probably I need to create two For loops, one to loop through all records, and inside it another loop to go through each customer record. It assigns first channel, then it checks if it is "Direct", then it goes to the next record, until the end of the loop.

Comment: Can you clarify if the date is m/d/y or d/m/y?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Convert `Date` to datetime so you can sort by `Date` (use `format="%m/%d/%y"` if your dates are in this format instead).
2. Define `condition_i` and `condition_ii` to account for your new logic: you want to keep *for each `Customer ID`*: (i) *all rows* if `Channel` is `Direct` for all rows; or (ii) *only rows where `Channel` is **not** `Direct`*, if not all rows for `Channel` are `Direct`.
3. Group on `Customer ID` then aggregate by `first` and `last`, respectively.
4. Merge the dataframes resulting from the groupbys.

```
df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"], format="%d/%m/%y")

df = df.sort_values(by="Date")

condition_i = df.groupby("Customer ID")["Channel"].transform(
    lambda x: all(x == "Direct")
)

condition_ii = (
    df.groupby("Customer ID")["Channel"]
    .transform(lambda x: any(x != "Direct"))
    .loc[df["Channel"] != "Direct"]
)

first = (
    df[(condition_i) | (condition_ii)]
    .groupby("Customer ID", as_index=False)
    .first()
    .rename(columns={"Channel": "Fist Channel"})
)

last = (
    df[(condition_i) | (condition_ii)]
    .groupby("Customer ID", as_index=False)
    .last()
    .rename(columns={"Channel": "Last Channel"})
)

out = pd.merge(
    first[["Customer ID", "Fist Channel"]], last[["Customer ID", "Last Channel"]]
)
```

```
   Customer ID Fist Channel Last Channel
0            1        Email       Search
1            2         Paid        Email
2            3       Direct       Direct
```

Comment: Thanks. This gave me the first channel and last channel, but how can I say if it is Direct then look for the next value? notice the difference between my output and your output.

Comment: @TarekSoukieh I've updated the answer to deal with that. Note that it's generally not a good idea to iterate over dataframe rows, so instead we identify conditions that represent the logic we want to apply, and perform operations on the filtered dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

You can [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) and use a custom [`groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) with `'first'`/`'last'`:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], dayfirst=False)

out = (df
   .sort_values(by='Date')
   .groupby('Customer ID', as_index=False)
   .agg(**{'First Channel': ('Channel', 'first'),
           'Last Channel': ('Channel', 'last')
          })
)
```

Output:

```
   Customer ID First Channel Last Channel
0            1         Email       Direct
1            2        Direct        Email
2            3        Direct       Direct
```

Comment: Thanks. This gave me the first channel and last channel, but how can I say if it is Direct then look for the next value? notice the difference between my output and your output.

Answer (score 0):

Before I start your output should be like that according to your input values. You'll see if you check your input and output again.

```
Customer ID, First Channel, Last Channel
1   Email   Direct
2   Direct  Email
3   Direct  Direct
```

Firstly convert your date column to datetime.

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
```

After that sort your dataframe by Customer ID and Date

```
df = df.sort_values(by=['Customer ID', 'Date'])
```

Find your first channel.

```
first_channel = df.groupby('Customer ID')['Channel'].first().reset_index()
```

Find your last channel

```
last_channel = df.groupby('Customer ID')['Channel'].last().reset_index()
```

Merge first_channel and last_channel on Customer ID.

```
final= pd.merge(first_channel, last_channel, on='Customer ID')
```

your final will have "Customer ID, Channel_x, Channel_y" So need to change column names. So you need to use that.

```
final.columns = ['Customer ID', 'First Channel', 'Last Channel']
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach:

1. First change 'Date' values to proper dates (using [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html)) and apply [`df.sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html).
2. Next, use [`df.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) on 'Customer ID', select 'Channel' and pass a custom function to [`groupby.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.apply.html).
3. Custom function:

   - We create a boolean mask `m` to check for values that are not 'Direct' (using [`Series.ne`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.ne.html)).
   - We use [`idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.idxmax.html) to find the index of the first and last value that doesn't equal 'Direct'. That it to say, in both directions (using `[::-1]` to reverse `m`) will we get the first `True` (i.e. the first not-'Direct') if it exists, else we will get a `False` (i.e. a 'Direct').
   - Finally, we use [`Series.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.loc.html) to get the values associated with the retrieved index values, turn the result into a `df` with [`Series.to_frame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_frame.html), transpose it with [`df.T`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.T.html#pandas.DataFrame.T), and use [`df.rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) to add the desired names ('First_Channel', 'Last_Channel'). This result gets returned to `groupby.apply`.

```py
# assuming the pattern: day / month / year
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%d/%m/%y')

def f(s):
    m = s.ne('Direct')
    idx = [m.idxmax(), m[::-1].idxmax()]
    df = (s.loc[idx]
          .to_frame()
          .T
          .rename(columns=dict(zip(idx, ['First Channel', 'Last Channel']))))
    return df

out = (df.sort_values('Date')
       .groupby('Customer ID', as_index=False)['Channel']
       .apply(f))

out

   Customer ID First Channel Last Channel
0            1         Email       Search
1            2          Paid        Email
2            3        Direct       Direct
```

---

Alternative method could be to use [`next`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next). Something like this:

```py
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%d/%m/%y')

def f2(s, last=False):
    if last:  # for "last", we reverse the list
        L = s.to_list()[::-1]
    else:
        L = s.to_list()
    # try to generate first non-'Direct' value, else return 'Direct'
    return next((elem for elem in L if elem != 'Direct'), 'Direct')

out2 = (
    df.sort_values('Date')
    .groupby('Customer ID', as_index=False)
    .agg(**{
        'First Channel': ('Channel', f2),
        'Last Channel': ('Channel', lambda s: f2(s, last=True))
    })
)

out2.equals(out)
# True
```